# Different output for easy visualization

Tags: sqlite, charts, visualization

I recently wrote an online assessment for the ML role of Mercari. While we were told that we would have a bunch of ML and DL-related MCQs, they gave us a test that I believe was fit for a Data Analyst role instead. They said that we could visualize our results if we wanted, and here lies my issue.

Here are the descriptions of the three tables-

Table 1: users

Columns -

- user_id (PK)
- created

Table 2: listings

Columns-

- item_id (PK)
- created (time the listing was created, not to be confused with users.created)
- lister_id
- category_id
- category_name
- price

Table 3: transactions

Columns-

- transaction_id (PK)
- created (Time the transaction occurred)
- item_id
- buyer_id
- seller_id

What I was trying to do was to find the following-
For each category, calculate the average value per transaction (in whole numbers) for each month.

My query was so-

```
SELECT category_name, ROUND(AVG(price)) As average,
strftime('%m', datetime(transactions.created)) as month from transactions, listings 
WHERE transactions.item_id = listings.item_id 
GROUP by strftime('%m', datetime(transactions.created)), category_name
```

Which gave me an output like this

```
category_name          average          month
Apparel                2650             3
Apparel                2180             4
Books                  1010             4
Electronics            4480             4
.
.
.
```

This doesn't make a good chart in MS Excel at all.

If I wanted an output like so

```
Month      Apparel       Books       Electronics
3          2650          0           0
4          2180          1010        5600
.
.
.
```

instead, which, first of all, looks better in the sheets, and I can also generate an intuitively easy-to-understand bar chart very easily.

Can I have any suggestions on how to change my query such that the columns in the output are the categories themselves, beside the month column?